# How would I use GNU Parallel for this while loop?

Tags: shell-script, files, gnu-parallel

So I have a while loop:

```
cat live_hosts | while read host; do \
    sortstuff.sh -a "$host" > sortedstuff-"$host"; done
```

But this can take a long time. How would I use GNU Parallel for this while loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't use a while loop.

```
parallel "sortstuff.sh -a {} > sortedstuff-{}" <live_hosts
```

---

Note that this won't work if you have paths in your `live_hosts` (e.g. `/some/dir/file`) as it would expand to `sortstuff.sh -a /some/dir/file > sortedstuff-/some/dir/file` (resulting in `no such file or directory`); for those cases use `{//}` and `{/}` (see [`gnu-parallel` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) for details):

```
parallel "sortstuff.sh -a {} > {//}/sortedstuff-{/}" <live_hosts
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `tee` with `parallel` when putting the output into `sortedstuff`? So I can see the output as it goes.

Comment: @Proletariat - you want to output to terminal too ? Just replace `>` with `| tee` e.g. the first command becomes  `parallel "sortstuff.sh -a {} | tee sortedstuff-{}" <live_hosts`

Answer (score 3):

As an old-school "do one thing and do it well" Unix guy, I'd put the string substitution stuff into a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sortstuff.sh -a "$1" > sortedstuff-"$1"
```

If you call it `wrapper.sh`, the `parallel` command to call it would be:

```
parallel wrapper.sh < live_hosts
```

Note that you don't need `cat` for this kind of thing, which saves an external program invocation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* `parallel`, since the body of the loop doesn't depend on previous iterations. Just start a new background process for each host.

```
while read host; do
    sortstuff.sh -a "$host" > sortedstuff-"$host" &
done < live_hosts
wait    # Optional, to block until the background tasks are done
```

`parallel` does make it easier to manage certain aspects, though; you can limit the number of jobs running in parallel more easily.

Comment: If `wc -l live_hosts` is more than the number of disk spindles or CPU cores — depending on whether the task is I/O or CPU-bound — you're going to eat up a lot of the advantage you get from parallelism with a solution like that. The ability of `parallel` to limit the number of jobs isn't just nice, it's near-essential, if processing speed is your goal.